# Laptop internet connection from SIM card's wi-fi, instead of smartphone's mobile hotspot wi-fi

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, smartphone

When traveling, we usually connect our laptop to our smartphone's wi-fi hotspot. In other words, the smartphone's wi-fi subscription, on its SIM card, is projected for the laptop to use/piggyback.

Is it possible instead to somehow make the laptop access the smartphone's SIM card directly instead? In the same way that the laptop has an SD card slot, is there such a thing as a SIM card slot or adaptor for laptops? The idea is to not have to require two hardware devices running at the same time (smartphone + laptop) just to have mobile internet when travelling. We just want to need the laptop in order to access the internet, not both

Comment: You need a WWAN card for the laptop that will use the Smartphone SIM card. WWAN cards are available for some laptops. We need a phone when traveling, so it is not really an extra burden to carry a phone plus the laptop.

Comment: so the SIM card is supposed to slide into the WWAN card somewhere? it seems kind of large to fit in a laptop https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/391321771615-0-1/s-l1000.jpg

Comment: You would have to ask the WWAN manufacturer about interchangeability. The SIM card from my iPhone 4s did not fit in my iPhone SE.

Comment: Your smartphone doesn't have a "Wi-Fi subscription on its SIM card". It has a cellular wireless data plan subscription on its SIM card. This is a way to connect to the Internet that does not use Wi-Fi at all. Wi-Fi and 4G/LTE cellular wireless data are two very different wireless networking technologies.

Comment: @John I'm asking about SIM card in the WWAN card in the laptop

Comment: You need to ask the WWAN Manufacturer for a SIM card (or where you purchased the computer). That would be a different card that your Phone and carry an added subscription price.

Comment: are you saying a WWAN doesn't accept phone SIMs?

Comment: SIM cards are not necessarily interchangeable. It appears that is the case here.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: What I am saying is that you cannot assume your phone SIM will fit in the WWAN card.

Comment: I never knew there were different size SIM cards, besides the mini-cut-out of the standard size